# Submitting a blank form to my website running on flask makes it return an internal server error

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, web

I'm running my webserver in flask at [NumbersIndia.com](http://numbersindia.com) . When I try to submit a balnk form the form at http://numbersindia.com/flask_hello_world.fcgi/track_mobile_numbers or the pincode form I get an internal server.
Here is the code for pincode route.

```
@app.route('/find_pin_codes', methods=['POST','GET'])
def pincodes():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form["number"] != "":
            number = request.form['number']
            number = number.replace(" ","")
            number = number.replace("-","")
            number = number.strip()
            strnumber = number
            try:
                number = int(number)
                num = pinCodes.query.filter_by(pincode = number).first()
                return render_template('pincodes.html', pincode = "Pincode : "+strnumber, 
                                    officename = "Office name : "+num.officename,  
                                    taluk = "Taluk : "+num.taluk, 
                                    district ="District : "+ num.district,
                                    state = "State : "+num.state
                                    )
            except:
                return render_template('pincodes.html', 
                                    pincode = "Pincode : "+strnumber, 
                                    officename = "Invalid pincode, try again")
        else:
            return render_template('pincodes.html', 
                                    pincode = "Pincode : "+strnumber, 
                                    officename = "Invalid pincode, try again")

    else:
        return render_template('pincodes.html')
```

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Comment: @limelights I'm sorry, but I don't know what stack trace means. Can you point me to a link.

Comment: The error you get when the server crashes :)

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: No, the server logs - not the error message on the page :)

Comment: My host is a shared one and searching for my IP is not giving any results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68214/discussion-between-wally-and-limelights).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your form is submitted blank trying to access `request.form["number"]` fails with a `KeyError` because the dictionary `request.form` does not have the key `"number"`. You can solve this by changing

```
if request.form["number"] != "":
```

to

```
if request.form.get("number", "") != "":
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer works. But can you please explain your answer?

Comment: You're submitting an empty form that does not contain the key `number` therefore Python is raising a `KeyError`. Using ´get()` with the default value `""` instead will not raise the exception and thus not crash when trying to access that key. If you had access to the weblogs you'd see the `KeyError`.